# sorting results of aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have written a query to get the latest records per Id from my ES. 
But the result of this query only does the inner sorting and chooses the latest records. Now I need the results that I got to be sorted by date.

This is my query:

```
{
   "size":0,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "base":"XYZ"
               }
            },
            {
               "match":{
                  "Type":"low"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "sources":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"Id"
         },
         "aggs":{
            "latest":{
               "top_hits":{
                  "size":1,

                  "_source":{
                     "includes":[
                        "base",
                        "Type"
                     ]
                  },
                  "sort":{
                     "orderDate":"desc"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please share a sample doc and index mapping

Comment: sample doc:          {
  "_index": "XXXX",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "bGd3qWgBnyB5Q6tB0Zjb",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "qtyFulfilled": 1.5,
    "@timestamp": "2019-02-01T14:30:27.784Z",   
    "base": "BTC",
    "Type": "LIMIT",
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2019-02-01T14:30:27.784Z"
    ],
    "orderDate": [
      "2019-02-01T14:30:27.727Z"
    ]
  }

Comment: The results of my query give my the latest doc of each Id.  like for id 1 the latest doc, then for id 2 the latest doc. But I need the order of this end result to be sorted as well. Like a sorting on the result of the aggregation.

Comment: Hey, you shared a result of the query. I wanted to know how all the fields you are querying on look like in a document stored in elastic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is sorting the buckets by another another bucket. You can achieve this in two ways:

(a) By [bucket_sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html) aggregation

(b) by using `order` param for terms aggregation referencing to another bucket.

#### (a) bucket_sort aggregation

This aggregation sorts the buckets of its parent multi-bucket aggregation. You can specify the field(s) based on which the buckets will be sorted. Using this, the query for your case will be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "base": "XYZ"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Type": "low"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "source": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "base",
                "Type"
              ]
            },
            "sort": {
              "orderDate": "desc"
            }
          }
        },
        "latestOrder": {
          "max": {
            "field": "orderDate"
          }
        },
        "bucket_sort_order": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": {
              "latestOrder": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "term": {
      "status": "yes"
    }
  }
}
```

In the query above I have used a max aggregation named as `latestOrder`. This aggregation gives us the value for latest `orderDate`. If we look as the top hit aggregation the document returned by it will have the same `orderDate` as returned by the max aggeration i.e. `latestOrder`. The reason being we have ordered top hit by `orderDate` in desc and limited the size to one, which is equivalent to max `orderDate`.

`latestOrder` works as a sorting field for us which is then used in the `bucket_sort` aggregation to sort the parent buckets which are the buckets returned by terms aggregation.

#### (b) `order` param in terms agg

We use the similar approach as above. We use max aggregation `latestOrder` and reference it in `order` param of terms aggregation. So the query will be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "base": "XYZ"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Type": "low"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "source": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "order": {
          "latestOrder": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "base",
                "Type",
                "orderDate"
              ]
            },
            "sort": {
              "orderDate": "desc"
            }
          }
        },
        "latestOrder": {
          "max": {
            "field":"orderDate"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "term": {
      "status": "yes"
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE in queries**: Based on discussion in comments added post_filter.

Comment: Can I filter the result that i get from the above aggregation to get  only the docs with base=" xyz" ?? I tried post_filter an bucket_filters but no success.

Comment: It's doing the same. I haven't change the query that you were using to filter the results. The query already has a condition to match base="XYZ". You can change XYZ to xyz.

Comment: Also I request you to please upvote and accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: This is a sample data. I need to query the result that I get based on terms in the buckets. The query I did earlier is required and based on that result, the aggregation was done. Now post the aggregation I need to do another filter to get out some docs only that have a specific value in one of the fields that are present in includes [] . Eg. after the aggregation I got docs with different status :some yes and some no, i need only the ones with yes.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: You have two conditions say X and Y. You first want to filter documents by condition X, then on the filtered documents you want to apply aggregation, after aggregation you want to further filter the documents by condition Y. So you want to run aggregation on documents filtered by condition X but want final documents filters based on condition X and Y.

Comment: yes yes that is exactly what I want! First a set of conditions in bool query as given and after aggregation just one condition.

Comment: In this case condition Y is known beforehand, right?

Comment: yes! it is a field called status. I just want the docs which have status as 'yes' and  I want to exclude the docs with the status as  'No'.

Comment: Ok I'll update my answer based on this in few minutes.

Comment: You have to just add a post filter for this. Updated both queries in answer.

Comment: I tried the post filter earlier but it did not filter the aggregation result only the first query result. I tried your code. It did not work . I am still getting the docs with status 'no'

Comment: Post filter doesn't filter aggregation result. Thats why I clarified the requirement first. Post filter runs after aggregation.

Comment: Oh I need something that could filter the aggregation result further. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You want top hits with status=yes?

Comment: If you want only top hits to be filtered and have rest of result same then you can use filter aggregation. I'll update the answer further if that is the requirement. Or just post another question and share the link.

Comment: First get top hits then from those only the ones with status='yes'. Only after getting the top hits for each id not before getting the top hits.

Comment: Its still unclear. Lets say by aggregation you get two results one against id A and another against id B. Top hit of A has document with status = no and B with status = yes. So in aggregation result you want only the one which is for id B?

Comment: yes yes. what you understood is  absolutely right. should I write another post with sample data and this query

Comment: Yes sure do that. Also up vote and accept this if this solved your initial problem of sorting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499834/sorting-aggregation-resultset-in-elasticsearch-and-filtering. Here is the link to the new question. Any help would be great.

Comment: Sure will do that.

Comment: "highestPriceOrder": {
          "max": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        },
    "bucket_sort_order_price": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": {
              "highestPriceOrder": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }
          }
        }                                                                                                                            if I add this before latest order sub agg in the code you provided it should first order by highest price and then by latest date right?

Comment: Yes, but sorting done by `bucket_sort_order` won't be in relation to `bucket_sort_order_price`. Effectively the bucket order appearing at the end will cause the ordering. So any other bucket order before the last one will be irrelevant.

Comment: Is there any way I could sort the buckets  first by price and then by orderDate if price values are the same?

Comment: Based on the price and date of the document in the top hit?

Comment: yes. After the aggregation (top hit) from the different docs I have, I would like to sort them first based on price and if that comes to a tie then the orderDate.

Comment: If this is the case then I don't think there is a way since we are dealing with top hits which further can't have sub aggregation. I have to give it a try to check if there can be a way around.

Comment: The `Max` aggregation works only on numeric fields. Is there a way to sort by text fields?

Comment: @sox please post separate question for the same with the relevant details.

Comment: @NishantSaini done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557040