# Sorting aggregation resultset in Elasticsearch and filtering

Tags: elasticsearch

Data sample in Elasticsearch index:

```
"_source": {
"Type": "SELL",
"Id": 31,
"status": "YES",
"base": "FIAT",
"orderDate": "2019-02-01T05:00:00.000Z",
}
```

I need to 
1. Filter the records based on 'base'=? and 'Type'=?  THEN 
2. get the top of stack or latest records for these filtered records for each Id and THEN 
3. from the results of these I need only the records with 'status'= 'YES'.

Elasticsearch query I wrote:

```
 {
   "size":0,       
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            { "match":{ "base":"FIAT" } },                
            { "match":{ "Type":"SELL" } }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "sources":{
         "terms":{ "field":"Id" },
         "aggs":{
            "latest":{              
               "top_hits":{
                  "size":1,                      
                  "_source":{
                     "includes":[
                        "Id",
                        "orderDate",
                        "status"
                     ]
                  },
                  "sort":{ "orderDate":"desc" }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Based on my findings, top hits can't have sub aggregation and therefore it won't be possible to filter buckets further. Best option would be to do that filtering in application code.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using composite aggregations.

[Composite Aggregations in ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html)

Comment: Hey Seetha, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your answer doesn't mention what is wrong or how your solution can work. Please add a more detailed explanation. Also explain how the solution can be implemented, and avoid reliance on links since if the link is broken in a few years, the answer won't help anyone landing on this page.

Comment: This is the official documentation from Elasticsearch team. As far as I know there is no better documentation than ES official one's. I feel instead of writing long answers just for the sake of community guidelines, this link is self explanatory.